# Vue-xlsx accessing json data

Tags: vue.js, xlsx

I am using a vue xlsx library to parse an excel sheet but I am having trouble accessing the returned json in my methods. I would like to able to do use the data in the from the collection that is being displayed in the template. How can I achieve what I am trying to do in the sendJson method?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="file" @change="onChange" />
    <xlsx-read :file="file">
      <xlsx-json>
        <template #default="collection">
          <div>
            {{ collection }}
          </div>
        </template>
      </xlsx-json>
    </xlsx-read>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { XlsxRead, XlsxJson } from "vue-xlsx";

export default {
  components: {
    XlsxRead,
    XlsxJson,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      file: null,
      collection: null,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      this.file = event.target.files ? event.target.files[0] : null;
      console.log("object", this.collection);
    },

    sendJson() {
      // for item in collection,
      // console.log(item.name)
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: What is output of `{{ collection }}` ?

Comment: Based on docs, `collection` should be an Array with objects, so you can iterate using `v-for`

Answer (score 0):

```
methods: {
  onChange (event) {
    this.file = event.target.files ? event.target.files[0] : null
  },
  getData (colection) {
    this.tempData = colection
    return colection
  }
}
```

This solution worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).